# Augmented reality 3D reconstruction

Tags: android, sdk, augmented-reality, vuforia, 3d-reconstruction

I want to develop an android augmented reality application, in which app should have a function to reconstruct a destructed objects(ex : buildings/statues) as shown in the following video link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOVjISxlhpU

I have gone through metaio, wikitude and vuforia sites each has some difficulties it self. and at Last i found vuforia has a feature call Smart Terrain where it is used for 3D animation and game development , the issue is only limited tutorials available to develop a customized application.
With that above link i found armedia.it and hyperspaces.inglobetechnologies.com those too have limited tutorials with the code.

Please let me know if any other SDK available their to fulfill my app feature share if there any useful tutorial to do such for the above sdk's

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want help here, you really need to ask specific questions, not for general guidance.

Comment: Have you find the answer? I've been searching this for a while

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there are any publicly available tools that can help you do this, except perhaps that armedia app.  Reading through it, it seems like their approach is kind of laborious and fragile (align photos of user viewpoints with accurate 3D model).  If you can't work through the tutorials these tools have, then posting here isn't going to get you what you want: SO is for asking specific technical questions (e.g., help fixing problems in code you have tried to build), not for general guidance and help.

FWIW, Vuforia's visual tracking will not work for something like this, I don't think, as is aimed at MUCH smaller scale things (for which you can build a target or object);  typically things smaller than a person.  Metaio is no longer available (Apple bought them).

Non-visual tracking (GPS + orientation) is not sufficient to attain this kind of tight registration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. In armedia(hyperspace of inglobe) I found they only allow us to maintain the target manager and assign 3D models as assets to that specific target (but that is advanced one than vuforia and useful). The user end is an already developed application and its available for iOS only. There is no sample application available to understand the code and they mentioned as advanced tutorial and android app are coming soon.

Comment: When considering vuforia they mentioned in article "Good props are no smaller than a can of vegetables, and no larger than a big cereal box. The stage itself can be as large as dining table." so i planned get a small part of a real world object and try it out.